# How can I create a list of each item in another list, and the count of how many times that item appears?

Tags: c#

So I have a list of items -> A, B, C, D.

C and D are included more than once, and A and B, more than twice. This list can go on and on, so we do not know how many times an item will be included.

[image: list]

I need to create a new list that will have the item in one column and the number of instances of that item in another column, but I do not know how to do this. I may need to use a tuple or a class, but I am not fully sure how to implement either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually need is to `Group` the items of your list and perform a group operation, which is `Count` in your case to calculate how many times does it exist.

This is how you may initialize your list:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B" };
```

and then you will group it using `GroupBy` function and apply the `Count` aggregate function on each group.

```
myList
.GroupBy(item => item)
.Select(g => new {Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
.ToList();
```

This will result in the table you need.

Comment: Jumping in just to flag that while both answers are correct, its important to know that Rahul's answer will evaluate *lazily*, as a result of it just being `.GroupBy()`, while Raamyy's answer will evaluate *immediately* as a result of the `.ToList()` chained at the end forcing the execution. [Here](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/750/deferred-vs-immediate-query-execution-linq#:~:text=The%20basic%20difference%20between%20a,Average()%2C%20Max()%20etc.) is an article on understanding how this works and what this means

Comment: Yes that's exactly correct @Narish, thanks for clarifying! Raul's answer may perform better in huge data size situations as not all the data will be loaded into the memory at once in my solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```
var myList = new List<String>() { "A","B", "C", "D","A","B", "C", "D", "A","B"};
var grp = myList.GroupBy( x => x );
foreach( var g in grp )
{
  Console.WriteLine( "{0} {1}", g.Key, g.Count() );
}
```

[DOTNET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cwHPCE)

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] items = new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B' };
Dictionary<char, int> counts = new();
foreach(char c in items)
{
    if (counts.TryGetValue(c, out int n))
    {
        counts[c] = n + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        counts.Add(c, 1);
    }
}
```

While not a one liner, a simple and fast option.

Answer (score 1):

> I may need to use a tuple or a class, but I am not fully sure how to implement either...

Since you mentioned you may want to use a `class`, here is an example:

```cs
public class TextCount
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Initialize the list of strings
        List<string> data = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B" };

        // Use LINQ to group the strings by their value and count the number of occurrences of each string
        List<TextCount> result = data
            .GroupBy(s => s)
            .Select(g => new TextCount { Text = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
            .ToList();

        // Print the results
        foreach (TextCount sc in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", sc.Text, sc.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2FRBbK